# What would be a basis of $L^2(\Omega )$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, inner-products

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,P)$ a probability space and $$L^2(\Omega )=\{random\ variable\  X\mid \mathbb E[X^2]<\infty \}$$
is a vector space. What would be a basis of $L^2(\Omega )$ ? I also know that $\left<X,Y\right>\longmapsto \mathbb E[XY]$ is a semi-inner product. Could we find an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\Omega )$ ?

Comment: I think knowledge of $\Omega$ is important here.

Comment: Every Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis and since $L^2(\Omega )$ is a Hilbert space, it has one too...but it really depends on $\Omega$ in how to express it

Comment: @user190080: Do you know a link where I can find example ?

Comment: check [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34561/orthonormal-basis-in-l2-omega-for-bounded-omega) for example....there are quite some examples, shouldn't be hard to find some more or to come up with